# Intellij data binding like Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, data-binding, intellij-idea

In Netbeans when creating a java swing form I can bind a jLabel's text to a value of jSlider. How to achieve this in Intellij Idea 14 Community edition. I can see a data binding wizard but I can't get it working.

Netbeans (Works as expected)
[image]

Intellij Bean Properties are empty

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From jetbrains help:
1. Make sure that your form contains components that are eligible for data binding.
I found that components jTextField and jCheckBox are eligible for data binding.
Using these components, we obtain Form:
[Data Binding Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FickY.png)
Your class for binding must contain fields with getter/setter methods.